# Tensorflow session error in universal sentence encoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving, sentence-similarity

I have the following code for the universal sentence encoder and it gives the following error(check below) once i load the model **into a flask api** and try hitting it:

'''

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5"
model_2 = hub.load(module_url)
print ("module %s loaded" % module_url)

def embed(input):
    return model_2(input)


def universalModel(messages):
    accuracy = []
    similarity_input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(None))
    similarity_message_encodings = embed(similarity_input_placeholder)
    with tf.Session() as session:
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
        message_embeddings_ = session.run(similarity_message_encodings, feed_dict={similarity_input_placeholder: messages})

        corr = np.inner(message_embeddings_, message_embeddings_)
        accuracy.append(corr[0,1])
    # print(corr[0,1])
    return "%.2f" % accuracy[0]
```

'''

**The following error it gives while using the model into the flask api:
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph is invalid, contains a cycle with 1 nodes, including: StatefulPartitionedCall**
Although this code runs without any error the in colab notebook.

**I am using tensorflow version 2.2.0.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

These two lines are intended to make tensorflow 2.x to tensorflow 1.x.

For Tensorflow 1.x, this is common issue while serving with flask, django, etc. 
You have to define a graph and session for inference,

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

```
# Create graph and finalize (finalizing optional but recommended).
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
  # We will be feeding 1D tensors of text into the graph.
  text_input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None])
  embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2")
  embedded_text = embed(text_input)
  init_op = tf.group([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
g.finalize()

# Create session and initialize.
session = tf.Session(graph=g)
session.run(init_op)
```

The input request can be handled through

```
result = session.run(embedded_text, feed_dict={text_input: ["Hello world"]})
```

For details 
https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_issues

For tensorflow 2.x session and graph is not required.

```
import tensorflow as tf
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5"
model_2 = hub.load(module_url)
print ("module %s loaded" % module_url)

def embed(input):
    return model_2(input)
#pass messages as list
def universalModel(messages):
    accuracy = []
    message_embeddings_= embed(messages)
    corr = np.inner(message_embeddings_, message_embeddings_)
    accuracy.append(corr[0,1])
    # print(corr[0,1])
    return "%.2f" % accuracy[0]
```

Comment: Also the same code is working on the jupyter notebook with tensorflow 2, so i don't get it why it's not working in the api ? @vivek-ananthan

Comment: This is the known issue of TF 1.x with Flask api. 
If you want to use with TF 2.x, no need to construct graphs and sessions like TF 1.x. 

repalce the first 2 lines with import tensorflow
so the tf 2.x will be loaed directly instead of tf1.x functionalities.

Comment: i am getting error while finding the correlation and loading model 5, can you please drill down my code with model 5 into a flask api code ? @vivek-ananthan

Comment: replace first 2 import statements to "import tensorflow"

let me know what error you getting after that

Comment: I am getting placeholder error as it is not present in v2, what else do i need to remove ? @vivek-ananthan

Comment: thanks a lot for your help vivek, for the correlation variable it is giving numpy error:
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall_3:0) to a numpy array. @vivek-ananthan

Comment: @AnkitKumar
facing the same problem, tensorflow 2 is working in jupyter notebook but not returning anything in Flask API.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890024/tensorflow-1-session-run-is-taking-too-much-time-to-embed-sentence-using-univers/62892910#62892910

Comment: Facing the same problem, tensorflow 2 code is working in jupyter notebook, but its not working in flask API.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890024/tensorflow-1-session-run-is-taking-too-much-time-to-embed-sentence-using-univers/62892910#62892910