# tensorflow 1 Session.run is taking too much time to embed sentence using universal sentence encoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, sentence-similarity

**Using tensforflow with flask REST API**

**How should i reduce the time for `session.run`**

I am using tf 1/2 in REST API, instead of serving it i am using it on my server.

i have tried tensorflow 1 and 2.

tensorflow 1 is taking too much time.

tensorflow 2 is not even returning the vectors for text.

**in tensorflow 1**
initialising is taking 2-4 seconds and `session.run` is taking 5-8 seconds.
and time is getting increased as i keep hitting the requests.

**tensorflow 1**

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tfo
import tensorflow_hub as hub
tfo.disable_eager_execution()

module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-qa/3"
# Import the Universal Sentence Encoder's TF Hub module
embed = hub.Module(module_url)

def convert_text_to_vector(text):
    # Compute a representation for each message, showing various lengths supported.
    try:
        #text = "qwerty" or ["qwerty"]
        if isinstance(text, str):
            text = [text]
        with tfo.Session() as session:
            t_time = time.time()
            session.run([tfo.global_variables_initializer(), tfo.tables_initializer()])
            m_time = time.time()
            message_embeddings = session.run(embed(text))
            vector_array = message_embeddings.tolist()[0]
        return vector_array
    except Exception as err:
        raise Exception(str(err))
```

**tensorflow  2**

**its getting stuck at `vector_array = embedding_fn(text)`**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-qa/3"
embedding_fn = hub.load(module_url)

@tf.function
def convert_text_to_vector(text):
    try:
        #text = ["qwerty"]
        vector_array = embedding_fn(text)
        return vector_array
    except Exception as err:
        raise Exception(str(err))
```

Comment: Hi, for tensorflow 2 code snippet what if you use 
vector_array = embedding_fn.signatures['question_encoder'](tf.constant(text)) . I tested it and it worked for me. Let me know if this is your intended use. Best

Comment: @smile i am using flask and it is not working in it. but both of the examples i posted and the solution you gave, all of them are working in Jupyter Notebook without any problem.

Comment: Hi, may be you can show how you get your parameters from flask. Or maybe first run it outside flask for better debugging. That way you can separate flask issues from tensorflow easily. Best

Comment: Order of calling : app.py -> controllers.py -> vectorisation.py. 

Controller calls convert_text_to_vector( which is inside vectorisation.py).

Argument while calling convert_text_to_vector is text = ['qwerty']

Comment: Hi, should I post a simple working example ? may be it might be useful? Best

Comment: yes please, any help is appreciated. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217791/discussion-between-pirate-and-smile).

Answer (score 0):

for the tensorflow 2 version I made few corrections. Basically I followed the example in [universal sentence encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-qa/3) that you provided.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-qa/3"
embedding_fn = hub.load(module_url)

@tf.function
def convert_text_to_vector(text):
  try:
      vector_array = embedding_fn.signatures['question_encoder'](
          tf.constant(text))
      return vector_array['outputs']
  except Exception as err:
      raise Exception(str(err))

### run the function
vector = convert_text_to_vector(['is this helpful ?'])
print(vector.shape())
```

Comment: working fine in jupyter notebook but not with flask.

Comment: Hi, could provide a minimal working example for the deployment on flask? Best

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource
from werkzeug.utils import cached_property

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-qa/3"
embedding_fn = hub.load(module_url)


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/embedding', methods=['POST'])
def entry_point(args):
    if args.get("text"):
        text_term = args.get("text")
        if isinstance(text_term, str):
            text_term = [text_term]
        vectors = convert_text_to_vector(text_term)
    return vectors



@tf.function
def convert_text_to_vector(text):
    try:
        vector_array = embedding_fn.signatures['question_encoder'](tf.constant(text))
        return vector_array['outputs']
    except Exception as err:
        raise Exception(str(err))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)

"""
 ----- Requirements.txt ----
flask-restplus==0.13.0
Flask==1.1.1
Werkzeug==0.15.5
tensorboard==2.2.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.6.0.post3
tensorflow==2.2.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.2.0
tensorflow-hub==0.8.0
tensorflow-text==2.2.1
"""
```

Comment: @smile flask app